# Propagating Mouse Events to Multiple Child Components for Synchronized Painting Behavior

Tags: swing

As indicated in the title I have a JPanel with two or more child JPanel Components and I would like to propagate a mouse event to all of the child components. Say for instance I have a moused dragged event which draws a rectangle in one of the child JPanel objects. I would like for the other JPanel children to draw the same thing in a synchronized fashion.

The first encountered issue is that typically only the topmost component residing "underneath" the mouse event receives notification of the particular mouse event which makes sense for most applications. I (quite nearly) got the behavior I was seeking instead by abandoning the MouseListener route normally used and using enableEvents() to enable various mouse events and then overriding processMouseEvent() and processMouseMotionMotionEvent() such that each function distributes the mouse events (with modified coordinates from the parent coordinates) to each child JPanel to draw necessary. However, I'm not sure if the route I chose is the best and wanted some more opinions on the matter.

One other method I would like to have implemented was to override the dispatchEvent( AWTEvent e ) method and dispatch events to each of the children panels by calling dispatchEvent on each of them, but unfortunately dispatchEvent( AWTEvent e ) is not overridable.

Any general assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the input code from the what should be painted code.

Have the panels share a model which tells them what should be painted. In your MouseListener(s) (or based on other input) add whatever needs to be painted to the model, which can then notify the panels to repaint themselves.